# PHP PDO execute standard function

Tags: php, function, pdo, die

New to PDO. Here is my function. We are connected to the database and everything is working but this function when called is killing off the rest of PHP to be executed. Obviously something is wrong with it.

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
        global $dbh;

        /*** set the error reporting attribute ***/
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

function selectall($table){
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM :table");
            $stmt->bindParam(':table', $table, PDO::PARAM_STR,20);
            $stmt->execute();
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
            return $result;
        }
```

Called on a page like this:

```
<?php $telephones = selectall('telephone'); foreach($telephones as $telephones) { echo $telephone['title'].', '; } ?>
```

/// EDIT - I have tried all of your methods and the function is still breaking when called on the page. Here is the entire code. Slightly modified for testing purposes.

```
try { 

        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);

        /*** set the error reporting attribute ***/
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM system";
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
            {
            $url = $row['url'];
            $election = $row['election'];
            $election_date = $row['election_date'];
            $sitename = $row['sitename'];
            }


        //FUNCTION

        function selectall($table){
            global $dbh;
             $sql = "SELECT * FROM telephone";
            foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row){
                print $row['title'] .' - '. $row['name'] . '<br />';
            }
        }


        /** close database connections **/
        $dbh = null;

    }

    catch(PDOException $e) { 

        echo $e->getMessage(); 

    }
```

The code outside the function ie. the one reflecting the table system is working perfectly Yet the one inside the function when called as a function later is killing off everything after it is called and is not executing.

Comment: You _cannot_ use  parameters for identifiers (db/column/tablenames), function names, etc. That is not how they work.

Comment: Is this really working? Where is `$dbh` coming from for starters? Also, how about checking for errors?

Comment: Like I said we are already connected to the database.

Comment: not your problem, but you should read up on the differences between bindparam and bindvalue.

Comment: If this is not how it is supposed to work then how should I achieve a similar result

Comment: you should lose the "all my code on one line" style very quickly. The reason is it's difficult for US to read.

Comment: turn on error reporting and display. this lets you see error messages, which help you discover your problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second line generates a fatal error, when you're trying to use an undefined variable (`$dbh`) as an object.

You need to import it from the global scope like this:

```
global $dbh;
```

or pass it as a parameter to the function.

After you fix this, your code still won't work, as you cannot use parameters for identifiers (table or column names, or even in limit and offset). Unfortunately you have to resort to string concatenation there.

Comment: OK I have removed the variable and instead but in the name of a table in the database. Still Nothing

Comment: Also added the code before this function as I think it will negate the need for the global like you have provided

Comment: No, you need to add the global statement to the function to tell php that $dbh is in the global scope.

Comment: quote() isnt suitable for identifiers - only values.

Comment: @RobinKnight when you call the function, `$dbh` is already set to null. Remove the `$dbh=null` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is: `$telephones as $telephones`

Try this:

```
$telephones = selectall('telephone'); foreach($telephones as $telephone) { echo $telephone['title'].', '; }
```

Comment: That is a silly typo. Thanks anyway we can all miss these things sometimes